# ASP.NET how to return pdf file as response without changing response header

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, response

I want to return a pdf file as response to some button click.
I succeeded to send the pdf file, but when i try to save it via the browser, it won't let me save it as a .pdf file (but as .aspx file)

here's the code:

```
Dim myWebClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim myDataBuffer As Byte() = myWebClient.DownloadData(LocalImageURL) ' LocalImageURL is some path to a pdf file
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

Response.BinaryWrite(myDataBuffer)
Response.Flush()

Response.End()
```

if I am adding also the following line before writing the byte array:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=report.pdf")
```

it does the trick, but the problem is that the page remains stuck (looks like it still waits for server response to come)

Comment: You don't. It's either a PDF or a webpage, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked and answered before.  Details are at the link below:

[asp.net VB.net file download handler not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057026/asp-net-vb-net-file-download-handler-not-work-properly/43083967#43083967)